# Laravel 5.2 Unicode Characters not encoded with or without blade

Tags: laravel, unicode, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My Controller Method include the code as follows

```
$News = DB::table('news')->skip(0)->take(1)->get();
return $News[0]->news_title;
```

and my database config file as

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
],
```

and the output looks

```
à®¤à¯Šà®´à®¿à®²à®±à¯à®±à®¿à®°à¯à®•à¯à®•à¯à®®à¯ à®µà®¿à®Ÿà¯à®¤à®²à¯ˆà®ªà¯ à®ªà¯à®²à®¿ à®®à¯à®©à¯à®©à®¾à®³à¯ à®ªà¯‹à®°à®¾à®³à®¿à®•à®³à¯
```

But when i'm trying to print this without Laravel its working fine. so i hope there is no issue with database.

Help me to sort this out .

Comment: what do you mean by without Laravel?

Comment: and exactly where you are getting this output? on your HTML?

Comment: Using core php its working fine. I mean without framework i just test the query

Comment: yes in my front end

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vigikaran/22b2c9d38a1b65970d072ac7e1341031 this code display the unicode title as expected.

Comment: can you show me your laravel code?

Comment: My Controller code is on the question

Comment: now I got, why you are getting this as because you are directly returning it without any view. You need to pass it to a view file.

Comment: I tried that. with blade and without blade template engine.

Comment: So what is it actually supposed to be? Just normal text or a base64 image or what?

Comment: it is a unicode text. (e.g : hindi )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi The issue has been solved.  I have change the database config as follows and now its working perfect.

```
'charset' => 'latin1',
'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public function convertUtf8( $value ) {
    return mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8' ? $value : mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8');
}

$News = DB::table('news')->skip(0)->take(1)->get();
return convertUtf8($News[0]->news_title);
```

Let me know if that worked!

By the way, are you trying to get the first item? You can do that easier. Just make a `News` model and do the following: `News::first();`

Comment: Hi i tried this way and still the string is fully decoded . i'm still getting characters such as ��?்��

Comment: No this is not making any changes , output as previous

Comment: @Vigikaran then unfortunately I don't know what would work, good luck with your search and let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Hi the issue is fixed. posted my solution . Thank you for your time

Comment: @Vigikaran no problem!

Answer (score 0):

use htmlentities($string, UTF-8) on your result string and then print it in laravel blade.

Comment: Getting this error htmlentities() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Comment: use htmlentities($string, UTF-8)

Comment: Hi the issue is fixed. posted my solution . Thank you for your time